# Is this breadth first or depth first?

Tags: javascript

From JavaScript the Good Parts ( modified ) :

```
var walk_the_DOM = function walk(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while(node) {
        walk(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

I'm having a difficult time analyzing this.  The DOM calls are simple enough.

It appears to be depth first as `walk()` will be repeatedly called for each level of depth.

If it is indeed depth first, what style of depth first is it - Pre-Order, In-Order, or Post-Order?

Here is the wikipedia on [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: Well, how does it compare to the pseudocode algorithms in that Wikipedia article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a DFS.

Here func is some action that happens on a node. So, as far as tree traversal is considered, we can drop func out for simplicity. Simplified traversal is :

```
function walk(node) {
   node = node.firstChild;
   while(node) 
   {
     walk(node);
     node = node.nextSibling;
   }
}
```

It's easy to notice now that you are calling the function "walk" one by one for all the children of current node. Also the function returns when it is done 'walking' on all its children. This is the property of DFS.

Comment: To decide pre/post/in order we need to look at the "func" function. Let's say "func" prints the node id. Since func is called on the current node before it is called on any of its children, it is pre-order traversal.

Answer (score 2):

Depth first. Because it always tries to traverse to the deeper level for every recursive call.

Comment: @Handy pre-order. It depends on the operations you want to do.